# SQL Server + Getting sales query for current and previous month

Tags: sql

I have a query below which draws the quantity of sales committed by men for the current as well as previous month, I like to find out if it is efficient to do it this way because it looks repetitive and if I were to get the report for a year then the query will be extremely long. Please advice if I can in any ways improve on this query, I am looking at performance improvements or even code reduction. Thanks.

```
Declare @CurrentMonth varchar(20)
Declare @PreviousMonth varchar(20)

Set @CurrentMonth =
( 
select count(*) from transact t
join card c
on (t.cardno = c.cardno)
join member m
on (c.Memberid = m.id)

       where mode ='1' 
       and voidby is null
       and gender='M'
       and month(transactdate) = month(getdate())             
)

Set @PreviousMonth = 
(
select count(*) from transact t
join card c
on (t.cardno = c.cardno)
join member m
on (c.Memberid = m.id)

       where mode='1' 
       and voidby is null 
       and gender='M'
       and month(transactdate) = month(dateadd(month, -1, (getdate())))

)

select  @currentMonth, @PreviousMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check result with your previous version. Quite important it can use index on `transactdate` if such exists.

```
declare @CurMonth int
declare @PrevMonth int

select @PrevMonth = sum(
        case 
        when transactdate < select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)
        then 1 else 0 end
    ),

    @CurMonth = sum(
        case 
        when transactdate > select dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)
        then 1 else 0 end
    )
from transact t
join card c on t.cardno = c.cardno
join member m on c.Memberid = m.id
where mode ='1' 
and voidby is null
and gender='M'
and transactdate >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
    and transactdate < dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0)
```